# PHP link to redirect back to account page

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, echo

So I have a bit of PHP code I'm working on for a website, and I've been trying to figure out how to make the username become a link to go back to a page called customer.php, where the customer's name is displayed after their name is selected from a list on another page. There is simply no way to redirect back to the customer account page (customer.php) after you've clicked on the customer name from the customer_select.php page unless you use back buttons. This code is static, but I'd like to implement a link that encompasses the customer name and number.

```html
<ul>
<!-- <li style="text-align:left;padding: 20px; color:white; background-color:black; width:100%"><?php echo "Current Customer: " . $_SESSION['customer'] . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 10) . $_SESSION['commission_display']; ?></li>-->
    <li style="text-align:left;padding: 20px; color:white; background-color:black; width:100%"><?php echo "Current Customer: " . $_SESSION['customerFirstName'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['customerLastName'] . ' (' . $_SESSION['customer'] . ')' . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 10) . $_SESSION['commission_display']; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look up the Anchor tag `<a href="customer.php">Go Back to Customer</a>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Would I be able to insert the anchor tag like `<?php echo "Current Customer: " <a href="customer.php"> . $_SESSION['customerFirstName'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['customerLastName'] . ' </a>(' . $_SESSION['customer'] . ')' . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 10) . $_SESSION['commission_display']; ?></li>` ?